# List the directories on depthlevel one in tar.gz

Tags: linux, find, grep

How can the directories on the level one can be listed in a tar.gz archive? E.g.
     \dir1\
     \dir2\
     \dir3\
     \dir4\
     \dir1\

Not \dir1\bla \dir1\bla2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `--exclude` option to exclude everything that's within a directory.

```
tar tfz archive.tar.gz --exclude '*/*'
```

Example:

```
[me@home]$ tar tfj CUnit-2.1-2-src.tar.bz2 | head -n5
CUnit-2.1-2/
CUnit-2.1-2/NEWS
CUnit-2.1-2/Makefile.am
CUnit-2.1-2/configure
CUnit-2.1-2/cunit.pc.in

[me@home]$ tar tfj CUnit-2.1-2-src.tar.bz2 --exclude '*/*'
CUnit-2.1-2/
```